# I need a shell-script to move the log's generated by server

Tags: bash, shell, automation

I have a requirement every week my server is generating the logs, and storing them in a disk/location on some days it's generating large size log's, so my disk is getting full, so i need to move all the log files **(except leaving previous day logs in the same location)** and move remaining to new location.

Idk at what perticular time the disk is filled with the logs, so i need a script to execute when ever the disk is almost full **when ever the disk reaches 80% or 90% of its storage capacity.** so automatically the script have to execute and move the logs to a new location

Comment: See [logrotate(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). That said, your question is technically off-topic here.

Comment: Idk at what perticular time the disk is filled with the logs, so i need a script to execute  when ever the disk is almost full **when ever  the disk reaces 80% of its storage capacity ** . so automatically the script have to execute and move the logs to a new location.

Comment: `"It allows automatic rotation, compression, removal, and mailing of log files. Each log file may be handled daily, weekly, monthly, or when it grows too large."` Set a maximum size for your logs or compute the allowable size based on the amount of free space remaining.

Answer (score 0):

The below can move logs older than 1 day to the new location, if the capacity threshold is (b)reached :

```
capacity_threshold=90  # limit set at 90%
current_usage=$(df -k /path/to/logs | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f5,5 | cut -d % -f1,1)       
[[ $current_usage -ge $capacity_threshold ]] && {
   find /path/to/logs -name "*.log" -mtime +1 -exec mv {} /new/path/. \;
}
```

Comment: Can u help me with the logic for when ever the disk is almost reaching it's max capacity of storage.

Comment: @Praveen see updated answer, now the files move would only occur if your logs filesystem is used 90% or more